# how to set appium max sanpshot depth

Tags: reactjs, appium, native

im testing a react native app using appium and i came across a problem while trying to inspect an element in a popup i have. While inspecting, it doesnt recognize the popup and its elements and all i can see is the elements in the back.
after a short research i think it can be related to the snapshop max depth setting and that i should set it to a higher value. i cant seem to understand HOW to do is exactly.
You have an idea on how to set it or an idea of anything that can help solve my problem?

Comment: Please post some code and clarify your question

Comment: @michaelrovinsky i work with classified programs so i wont be able to post code. i cant see the elements that i look for in the appium inpect. almost like they dont exist. when i try to look for it with the search icon i also cant view them

Comment: The information you provide seems to be insufficient to do anything helpful with. At least, try to describe your situation in short and clean centences and explain the very problem you face.

Comment: when i hover over the element i want to inspect in apium, appium cant identify this element and i cant see its details

Comment: It's hard to understand the problem without any code... I suggest to produce a _similar_ reproduceable example in a snippet (without any classified data) and post it here